# It's not working correctly, it outputs undefined?

Tags: javascript

```
function Rabbit(adjective) {
    this.adjective = adjective;
    this.describeMyself = function() {
        console.log("I am a " + this.adjective + " rabbit");
    };
}

// now we can easily make all of our rabbits
rabbit1 = new Rabbit("fluffy");
rabbit2 = new Rabbit("happy");
rabbit3 = new Rabbit("sleepy");

console.log(rabbit1.describeMyself());
console.log(rabbit2.describeMyself());
console.log(rabbit3.describeMyself());
```

The output:

```
I am a fluffy rabbit
undefined
I am a happy rabbit
undefined
I am a sleepy rabbit
undefined
```

Would it stop the undefined if I were to execute it as a .js file instead of a console? Or would it be the same?

Comment: When the code is run in browser console, the `describeMyself()` will return `undefined` as nothing is returned from that function.

Comment: *"It's working correctly, but it outputs undefined?"* - So in fact it is working *incorrectly*?

Comment: Here's improved code which **defines function on prototype**: `function Rabbit(adjective) {
    this.adjective = adjective;
}
Rabbit.prototype.describeMyself = function() {
    return "I am a " + this.adjective + " rabbit";
};

// now we can easily make all of our rabbits
rabbit1 = new Rabbit("fluffy");
rabbit2 = new Rabbit("happy");
rabbit3 = new Rabbit("sleepy");

console.log(rabbit1.describeMyself());
console.log(rabbit2.describeMyself());
console.log(rabbit3.describeMyself());`

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to console.log a function which will return nothing so result is shown as undefined. You need to just call the function as you already have console.log within it.. Try this

`rabbit1.describeMyself();`
`rabbit2.describeMyself();`
`rabbit3.describeMyself();`

Answer (score 0):

`describeMyself()` doesn't return anything explicitly so it returns `undefined` for each `console.log(rabbit1.describeMyself())` implicitly

Comment: How can I fix this issue? Do I add return; in the function.

Comment: @XTImpossible if you just want to print the message in `describeMyself()`, you don'y need `console.log(rabbit1.describeMyself())` , just call `describeMyself()` directly or if u want to do `console.log(rabbit1.describeMyself())`, then return the string from `describeMyself()` rather then doing `console.log()` in `describeMyself()`

Answer (score 0):

Your code is equivalent to this

```
function Rabbit(adjective) {
    this.adjective = adjective;
    this.describeMyself = function() {
        console.log("I am a " + this.adjective + " rabbit");
        return undefined; // <-- without a return statement, undefined will be returned.
    };
}

// now we can easily make all of our rabbits
rabbit1 = new Rabbit("fluffy");

var result = rabbit1.describeMyself(); // <-- the message logged to console and return undefined
console.log(result); // and print undefined again
```

So the solution is return string from the method

---

```
function Rabbit(adjective) {
    this.adjective = adjective;
    this.describeMyself = function() {
        return "I am a " + this.adjective + " rabbit"); // <-- return a string
    };
}

// now we can easily make all of our rabbits
rabbit1 = new Rabbit("fluffy");

console.log(rabbit1.describeMyself()); // <-- log the string value
```

---

or remove extra logs

```
function Rabbit(adjective) {
    this.adjective = adjective;
    this.describeMyself = function() {
        console.log("I am a " + this.adjective + " rabbit");
    };
}

// now we can easily make all of our rabbits
rabbit1 = new Rabbit("fluffy");

rabbit1.describeMyself(); // <-- this method will print to console and return undefined
```